# Formatting decimal places with R

Tags: r

I have single digit numbers. They may have 0, 1 or 2 places after the decimal.

I want at least one decimal place shown. Thus:

2 show as 2.0

If there is one decimal place, show it, but don't add an additional zero. So:

2.1 show as 2.1

If there are two decimal places, show both of them:

2.45 show as 2.45

Given `x <- c(1.8, 1.55, 1.5, 1)` I should get `(1.8, 1.55, 1.5, 1.0)`

Is this possible with `sprintf` or `format`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be achieved by combining `format` with `sub`

```r
> x <- c(1.8, 1.55, 1.5, 1, 1.23445, 100, -1)
# the pattern (?<=\\.\\d)0$ checks if the last number after . is a zero if so replace with nothing
> sub("(?<=\\.\\d)0$", "", format(x, digits=3), perl=T )
[1] "  1.8"  "  1.55" "  1.5"  "  1.0"  "  1.23" "100.0"  " -1.0" 
> sub("(^ *)(?=\\d)", "\\1+", sub("(?<=\\.\\d)0$", "", format(x, digits=3), perl=T ), perl=T)
[1] "  +1.8"  "  +1.55" "  +1.5"  "  +1.0"  "  +1.23" "+100.0"  " -1.0"
```

Comment: With this method can there be a "+" prefix for positive numbers? +1.55 for 1.55